# Consistent way to represent key sequences?

Tags: key-bindings, syntax, style

The macro `kbd` doesn't work for all desired input. For example, this results in an error:

```
(kbd "C-H-left")
edmacro-parse-keys: C-H- must prefix a single character, not left
```

and should be written as:

```
(kbd "C-H-<left>")
```

There is an alternative (vector) syntax:

```
[?\C-\H-x home]
```

but this representation also isn't unique: the vector above has the same meaning as

```
[(control hyper x) home]
```

Also, `(kbd "RET")` isn't `[return]`, but `?\C-m`. Same with `(kbd "DEL")` and others.

Forms `(kbd "\e\eq")` and `[?\e \?M-q]` represent the same key sequence, but have different values:

```
(kbd "\e\eq")  ; evaluated to "^[^[q"

[?\e \?M-q]    ; evaluated to [27 134217841]
```

Are all these syntax rules available in Emacs >= v22.x?

Which syntax is **consistent and regular**? Which mini-language describing key sequences has **fewer special cases**?

I found that I need to consult references every time I make a new key binding. Consider binding `ESC M-H-kp-2 C-PgUp` or similar.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to ask in your question?  "What syntax is preferred?" is pretty broad and will elicit opinion-based answers.  If you mean something like "what's the cleanest syntax" or "what's the least error-prone syntax" (or something else), please edit the post to reflect it.

Comment: Where are less special cases in syntax of mini-language?

Comment: Why should I care of difference between `\r` and `RET` or `<RET>` or `[return]`??